# How to run application on remote machine after open from local environment

Tags: c#, .net, impersonation

My goal is to open a windows application with different user credential in my CODEDUI test, after did a lot of Googling I have tried impersonation LLD but was unable to get it to work. I decided to open the remote desktop connection directly and instruct my code to launch the target application but the application is started in my local environment instead of the remote desktop.

With this code I can login to remote machine successfully.

```
var rdcProcess = new Process();
rdcProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%SystemRoot%\system32\cmdkey.exe");
rdcProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/generic:TERMSRV/MachineName/user:" + userName+ " /pass:" + "password";
rdcProcess.Start();

rdcProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%SystemRoot%\system32\mstsc.exe");
rdcProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/v " + "MachineName"; // ip or name of computer to connect
rdcProcess.Start();
```

Then i want to launch the application in this remote machine:

```
Apps = ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(@"application.exe");
```

Instead it launches the application from my local environment. What would I have to do to launch the application in the remote environment?

Comment: First see with a windows explorer (or from cmd.exe \servername) you can access the files before trying with software.  If windows explorer doesn't work then your software will not work.  The two computers need to be in the same group and use the same credential (except if admin) for it to work.  What version of windows are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your response. The two computers are in the same group and domain but with different credentials. i am using windows 8.1 Pro.

Comment: Can you connect change files by opening with a window explorer?  You should be able to type in URL \\MachineName.  Or from cmd.exe try cd \\MachineName.  You should be able to move to folder with cd.  Use dir to get a list of files in folders.  You can use wild card like cd abc*.  Then when you get to folder you can type application name.  I suspect the credentials on a file or folder has to be changed to have both accounts in the same user group

Comment: thanks so much for your response, i have found solution to the problem but in different way. i didn't realise that Launch method in CodedUI can be overloaded with userName, Password and Domain in CodedUI. in case someone else need this solution .      Apps = ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AUT"], null, null, "UserName",
                    password, "Domain");